# Program looping infinitly

Tags: java

I wrote program that take command from user and perform particular functionality.  However, there is something wrong with the functionality read and write input to file which cause the loop to run indefinitely.

```
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class cShell{

    static String Currentpath="C:\\";
    public String Current = Currentpath;

    static HashMap<String, ICommand> myhashData=new HashMap<String, ICommand>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


    myhashData.put("ltf", new cITF());
    myhashData.put("nbc", new cNBC());
    myhashData.put("gdb", new cGDB());
    myhashData.put("Tedit", new cTedit());

    do
    {


            System.out.print(Currentpath+"> ");

            String Input = null;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            if(scan.hasNext()){
                Input = scan.nextLine().trim();

            }

            //if(Input.equals("exit")){
            //  System.exit(0);
            //}

            if(myhashData.containsKey(Input))
            {
                ICommand myCommand=myhashData.get(Input);
                myCommand.Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Command");
            }


    }while(!"Input".equals("exit"));
  }
}
```

And here is the class which provide the functionality for read and write.

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 //import java.lang.System.*;

 public class cTedit implements ICommand{

     @Override
     public void Execute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         System.out.println("Enter the file name to be edited");
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String filename = scan.nextLine();

                 InputStreamReader cin = null;
         FileWriter out = null;

    try{
        cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        out = new FileWriter(cShell.Currentpath+"\\"+filename);
        System.out.println("Enter character, 'q' to quit");
        char c;

        do{
            c = (char) cin.read();
            out.write(c);
        }while(c!= 'q');
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    finally{

            try{
            cin.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File did not close");
        }
             }
       }
  }
```

The problem is that after the reading and writing, the program output the message "Invalid Command" which is defined inside the class cShell.  Can anyone point to me where this the cause..??

Answer (score 3):

The `do-while` loop will run forever becauses its termination condition is:

```
!"Input".equals("exit")
```

The *string* `"Input"` will **never** be equal to the string `"exit"`. You may want to use the variable `Input` instead:

```
!input.equals("exit")
```

**Note:**

- Try to follow Java naming conventions. Use 'mixedCase' for methods/variables and use 'CamelCase' for classes/interfaces. In other words, the variable name should be `input`, not `Input`.

Comment: I have changed that and now the Input is underlined red...I think it is because it contains null as declared and cannot be used with .equal

Comment: Declare it as an empty string `""`. Of course it depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
while(!"Input".equals("exit"));
```

to

```
while(!Input.equals("exit"));
```

As `"Input"` can never be equal to `"exit"` condition is always true and hence it loops infinitely.

For NPE you can add null checks

```
finally{

        try{
        if(cin != null)
           cin.close();
        if(out != null)
           out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File did not close");
    }
   }
```

Comment: Yes exactly but there is another problem, Invalid I declared contains null which cannot not be used with the .equal operator...

Comment: Don't initialize it to null then. Use empty String "".

Comment: Yes it works, but I have one more problem...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at cTedit.Execute(cTedit.java:100)
 at cShell.main(cShell.java:49)


  It pointed to the out.close() inside the Tedit class.  If I remove this out.close() the program ran into anothe infinite loop with the message 

Error: C:\kaka (Access is denied)
C:\\kaka> Enter the file name to be edited
Edit a file - Press Ctrl+z to end
Error: C:\kaka (Access is denied)

  C:\\kaka> Enter the file name to be edited
Edit a file - Press Ctrl+z to end

(C:\\kaka is equivalent to cShell.Currentpath)

Comment: It still do the same thing...looping infinitely...what might be the cause..?